# How to associate a CSS file

Tags: javascript, css, ibm-mobilefirst

When loading a html file using `load()`, how can I associate the HTML with a CSS FILE?

To load a JS file, I use:
`$ .getScript (path + "js / itt1_pag1.js");`

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to the same `script` tag where you load page1.js:

```
script
    $.getScript (path + "js/itt1_pag1.js");
    $('<link/>', {
       rel: 'stylesheet',
       type: 'text/css',
       href: 'path-to-file.css'
    }).appendTo('head');
script
```

Note that I had to remove the `<` and `>` signs surrounding "script", otherwise I could not submit the answer.

Comment: Correct. But it's important to note that one cannot be sure when the css will be fully loaded and applyed by the browser, it is always possible you end up viewing uncorrectly formatted html a few time. If css rules are not huge, may be better to hide the container, apply them programatically (with jQuery .css()) and then show it again.